# IOS error about Sinch framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, sinch

I want to do call function and I use Sinch.framework, but I had met this error when I add Sinch.framework to my project.

How to fix this error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have not added the required frameworks

```
AudioToolbox.framework
AVFoundation.framework
Security.framework
```

or added the other linker flags

```
-ObjC -Xlinker -lc++
```

you can find more info here
https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/ios/