# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode

I get an error while I'm trying to archive a new version of my app and I cannot figurate out what it cames from and how to fix it.

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The whole error here:

```
Ld /Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.app/app normal x86_64
cd /Users/adrianvidican/Downloads/MessengerX.1
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.3
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bolts -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKLoginKit -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMOAuth2 -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IQAudioRecorderController -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSQMessagesViewController -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSQSystemSoundPlayer -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MBProgressHUD -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MGSwipeTableCell -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProgressHUD -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCryptor-objc -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNGridMenu -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Reachability -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Realm -L/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SCSiriWaveformView -L/Users/adrianvidican/Downloads/MessengerX.1/Pods/Realm/core -F/Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/adrianvidican/Downloads/MessengerX.1/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS -F/Users/adrianvidican/Downloads/MessengerX.1/Pods/Fabric/iOS -F/Users/adrianvidican/Downloads/MessengerX.1/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/adrianvidican/Downloads/MessengerX.1/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks -F/Users/adrianvidican/Downloads/MessengerX.1/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks -F/Users/adrianvidican/Downloads/MessengerX.1/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/Frameworks -F/Users/adrianvidican/Downloads/MessengerX.1/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -F/Users/adrianvidican/Downloads/MessengerX.1/Pods/FirebaseStorage/Frameworks -F/Users/adrianvidican/Downloads/MessengerX.1/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks -F/Users/adrianvidican/Downloads/MessengerX.1/Pods/OneSignal/iOS_SDK/Framework -F/Users/adrianvidican/Downloads/MessengerX.1/Pods/SinchRTC -filelist /Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/app.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.3 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/app_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lBolts -lFBSDKCoreKit -lFBSDKLoginKit -lGTMOAuth2 -lGTMSessionFetcher -lGoogleToolboxForMac -lIQAudioRecorderController -lJSQMessagesViewController -lJSQSystemSoundPlayer -lMBProgressHUD -lMGSwipeTableCell -lProgressHUD -lRNCryptor-objc -lRNGridMenu -lReachability -lRealm -lSCSiriWaveformView -lc++ -licucore -lrealmcore-ios -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreText -framework CoreVideo -framework Crashlytics -framework Fabric -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseAuth -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseDatabase -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseStorage -framework Foundation -framework GLKit -framework GoogleSignIn -framework MapKit -framework MobileCoreServices -framework OneSignal -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SafariServices -framework Security -framework Sinch -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework VideoToolbox -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework CoreGraphics -weak_framework CoreLocation -weak_framework Foundation -weak_framework QuartzCore -weak_framework Security -weak_framework Social -weak_framework UIKit -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.build/app.app.xcent -framework PushKit -lPods-app -framework MessageUI -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/app_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/adrianvidican/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkxsgphkoxkxumbswtcudmwodhqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.app/app

 ld: framework not found Sinch
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: What's the minimum iOS requirement of your project? And have you checked this out ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775805/ios-error-about-sinch-framework

Comment: It works fine until xCode 9 and ios 11

Comment: "framework not found Sinch"  What is Sinch and how is it supposed to be linked to your app?

Comment: Sinch.com and I do not change anything on this, what could happen ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to trash everything that is in :

/Users/yourUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

and rebuild. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do the drill and try this:

1. Cmd + Shift + K
2. Cmd + Shift + Alt/Option + K
3. Build.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you get this if you have converted your app to swift 4 and have dependancies. If you have added any pods or frameworks go to them and and in the build settings search for swift language and set them to 3.2.

It may be that your frameworks have not been updated to work with swift 4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed mine by deleting all Sinch Frameworks in my projects and folders, deleting all contents in DerivedData, cleaning project.. downloading a new version from Sinch site and installing... Quit Xcode.. and restart Xcode. Run and build.